# How can I specify ProxyPassReverse for ProxyPassMatch across multiple target hosts?

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy

I'm using httpd `mod_proxy` to set up a CORS proxy, similar in spirit to [thingproxy](https://github.com/Freeboard/thingproxy) or [crossorigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/).  I've gotten as far as

```
SSLProxyEngine on
<LocationMatch "^/corsproxy/(https?)://([^/]+)/(.*)$">
    ProxyPassMatch "$1://$2/$3"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://my-site.org/"
    Header unset X-Frame-Options
</LocationMatch>
```

This works, in that you can visit `http://myhost/corsproxy/http://example.com/somepage` and it loads successfully.  The problem is, redirects still point directly to `example.com`, not to the equivalent proxied URL.

That's where `ProxyPassMatch` comes in, but I don't believe it is able to do regex matches against the target URL, so I can't extract the protocol, hostname, and path, as I did in `LocationMatch`.  Is there a workaround for this?  Maybe something I can do with `mod_rewrite`?

Before the comments show up: yes, I'm aware of the security ramifications, and yes, I'd like to try to do this entirely inside httpd instead of running a tool like the ones I linked to at the beginning of the question, since they introduce external dependencies (in both cases, NodeJS).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what else `ProxyPassReverse` normally does, but just for redirects I was able to use a `Header edit` directive:

```
Header edit Location ^http://(.+)$ "/corsproxy/http://$1"
Header edit Location ^https://(.+)$ "/corsproxy/https://$1"
```

I played with using a single line instead of two but ran into some strange behavior and it wasn't worth tracking it down.  I'd still like to know if there are other edge cases I might not be covering with this approach.